# How to render in Flutter using CustomPainter on click button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am rendering a specific custom component using `CustomPaint` class. I pass `size`, `painter` and `foregroundPainter` properties. How to trigger rendering of a foregorund overlay only if I press a button? In other worlds I would like to have an access to `paint` method from the outside and trigger it on my command.

Answer (score 0):

**test on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5e0fca0a208f286facb3b85073b301e6&null_safety=true)**

**code-snippet**

```
class MYWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MYWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MYWidgetState createState() => _MYWidgetState();
}

class MyPainterX extends CustomPainter {
  final double x;

  MyPainterX({
    required this.x,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.yellow;

    var path = Path();

    canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(0, size.width / 2), Offset(x, size.width / 2), paint);

    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

class _MYWidgetState extends State<MYWidget> {
  double xVal = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        CustomPaint(
          foregroundPainter: MyPainterX(x: xVal),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              xVal += 10;
            });
          },
          child: Text(
            "increase 10",
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But still I have to dynamically add something and calculate it's parameters (like length) so ideal for me would be accessing methods which has an access to canvas.

Comment: Do you mean to control canvas size? And can you include your customPainter  you can pass values through parameter. and controll canvas size though `CustomPaint`'s child.

Comment: No. I don't want to manipulate canvas' size. I would like to draw a line using `  canvas.drawLine(Offset(500, 25), Offset(555, 25), _clipStartEndLine)` which will be longer after button's click.

Comment: Are you animating those lines?

Comment: No. I would like to render line from point 0 to 100. After Click I would like to extend it e.g from 0 to 100 + x but `x` is known while button is pressed.

Comment: Answer updated on-tap it will increase by 10